# Exponential Power Tower

Tags: exponentiation, power-towers

My question is-
$$(4x)^{{{{\sqrt x}^{\sqrt x}}^ \cdots}^\infty}=0.0625$$
How to solve it?

Options-
(A)$2^{1/24}$
(B)$2^{1/48}$
(C)$4^{1/48}$
(D)$2^{1/96}$

I am confused how to solve this infinite power tree. Any help will be appreciated
Note: Multiple options or none of the options may be correct
My approach-
Took log on both sides then simplified to $xlog4x=log5-3$, then punched out it on a calculator but it says that no real solutions exists.

Comment: Please be more detailed in your question by showing what you have tried to do.

Comment: Is it $(4x)^{\sqrt x ^{...}}$ or is it $4(x^{\sqrt x^{...}})$?

Comment: First one is correct

Comment: That isn't what you have written.  Please edit your question.

Comment: @ArchitPasayat isn't option (A) & (C), the same? I suggest re-writing the question.

Comment: Ah yes i completely forgot to mention that none of the options or multiple options may be correct

Comment: For some reason I am unable to edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Too long for a comment.)

$(4x)^{{{{\sqrt x}^{\sqrt x}}^ \cdots}^\infty}=0.0625
\Longrightarrow (2\sqrt{x})^{{{{\sqrt x}^{\sqrt x}}^ \cdots}^\infty}=0.25$

Let $\sqrt{x}^{{\sqrt{x}}^{{\cdots \infty}}}=a$

We have $2^a\cdot a=0.25$

Solve for $a$ then solve for $x$?

Comment: Note: $a$ cannot be solved in elementary terms. You need to use the [product log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) to find $a$. Not only that, you will need to apply Lambert’s W function _again_ to get from $a$ to $x$ because infinite power towers cannot be solved using elementary functions.

Comment: @Kyky yes for that reason, I'm sure there's some errors in the question itself

Comment: @mourad nothing is wrong with the question. I am preparing for a Olympiad which asks extremely difficult questions and yes, i know that W function.